# How to calculate average by excluding first 300 measurements in Group 1 in r

Tags: r, filter, average

I have many 1-sec emission measurements and have grouped them by event number. However, I would like remove the first 300 measurements from group 1, and calculate the group average from 301 to the last measurement in this group. For the remaining groups, I will just calculate the group average using all measurements, no need to take out the first 300 seconds.

I knew the code to compute group averages without excluding the first 300 measurements in group 1, in something like:

```r
StartsSummary <- ddply(emission, "Group", summarize,  CO2_avg = mean(CO2_DC))
```

```r
emission <- data.frame(Group= c(rep(1, 400), rep(2, 305),rep(3, 200)), CO2_DC = c(rep(0.5, 350), rep(1, 400), rep(1.5, 155))
```

I expect the results as:

```
Group  CO2_avg
1      0.75    (excluding first 300 measurements in group 1)
2      1       (include all measurements in group 2)
3      1.3875  (include all measurements in group 3)
```

Comment: With `dplyr`, you can try `emission %>%
 arrange(Group) %>%
 filter(!row_number() %in% c(1:300))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine @TonyLadson and @tmfmnk into one filter statement.

```
library(dplyr)
emission <- data.frame(Group= c(rep(1, 400), rep(2, 305),rep(3, 200)), CO2_DC = c(rep(0.5, 350), rep(1, 400), rep(1.5, 155)))

emission%>%
  group_by(Group)%>%
  filter(!(Group == 1 & row_number() %in% 1:300))%>%
  summarize(CO2_Avg = mean(CO2_DC))

  Group CO2_Avg
  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1    0.75
2     2    1   
3     3    1.39
```

**Edit:** I switched the order of the `group_by()` and the `filter()` statements. This allows the statement to work in case the `Group` is in a different order or if you wanted the first 100 rows of `Group 2`.

Comment: Thank you, but what if the row_number for Group 1 does not start from 1? Say, a random number in each file?

Comment: Yep, this should work. My understanding is that each group gets its own row_number.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the real problem, the easiest way would be to do the calculation in two stages

```
library(tidyverse)

# Mean of groups 2 and 3 using all data                       
emission %>% 
  filter(Group != 1) %>%  # exclude group 1
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(mean(CO2_DC))


# Mean of group 1 exclusing the first 300 rows
emission %>% 
  filter(Group == 1) %>% 
  slice(301:n()) %>% 
  summarise(mean(CO2_DC))
```